# VirtualBox running on OSX host; Allocating more than 4GB of memory

Tags: macos, virtualbox, memory

I'm running a Windows 10 on OSX (latest. Sierra) and found that it is extremely slow when compiling a VS project.

To the best of my knowledge, I think the problem was that I have allocated 10 GB memory on Virtual Box, but the Activity Monitor says that I only got 4 GB memory allocated on it. Please see attached image.

[VirtualBox Memory allocation settings, Activity Monitor that says it only got 4 GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAQjF.jpg)

Any help would be much appreciated. I had another OSX (Yosemite) running Windows 8 at the office and on it, Activity Monitor reported 10 GB memory allocated in it.

Comment: Windows 10 64... or 32?

Comment: hoo. I don't remember for sure.

Comment: 32-bit OS would explain it most simply - it can't address more than 4GB, no matter how much RAM is actually available to it.